# Bootstrap not compatible with angular 5

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5. After installing ng-bootstrap there are few errors. Is ng-bootstrap not compatible with Angular 5, or are their any other packages that are compatible?

[image]

Comment: try to install ng-bootstrap like this `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Comment: You are NOT install ng-bootstrap. To install bootstrap install  jquery and popper http://colinstodd.com/blog/post/how-to-install-bootstrap-4-beta-in-angular-4-as-a-dependency. If you want install ng-bootstrap just npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: if you not know the difference between bootstrap and ng-bootstrap check https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

`ng-bootstrap` is now compatible with Angular 5 (since [5 Nov](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/commit/038e20a56aa23bdef39acbf46a350ebc90129701)).

---

You may indeed be right about `ng-bootstrap` not being compatible with Angular 5:

> **Dependencies**
>
> - **Angular** (tested with 4.0.3)
> - **Bootstrap 4** (tested with 4.0.0-beta.2)

But I can verify `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2` is compatible with *angular* modules `@5.0.5`, along with `npm@5.6.0`, `node@9.2.0` and `typescript@2.4.2` here.

(Also no issues with my `.angular-cli.json` loading a custom `styles.scss`, which I use for a few selective imports like `@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ng-bootstrap` instead of regular old bootstrap...

Try this:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

source: [ng-bootstrap docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I used ngx-bootstrap which is compatible  as ng-bootstrap is not compatible